# Parsing date YYYYMMDD'T'HHmmss.sss'Z'

Tags: javascript, date

Let's say that I receiving a date from api in format: `20191116T202021.000Z`

But unfortunately I'am not able to parse this data in javascript:

```js
  var dateToParse = "20191116T202021.000Z"
  var dateFormat = "YYYYMMDD'T'HHmmss.sss'Z'"

  var test = Date.parse(dateToParse, dateFormat)
  console.log(test)
```

What I want to achieve is to subtract current date with this dateToParse date and see difference in seconds, minutes and days.

Comment: Where did you get the info from that `Date.parse` takes a second argument?

Comment: It seems you're asking two questions in one: how to parse a string to a date and how to get the difference between two dates in days, minutes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no second argument support for `Date.parse`. Instead convert your input string to the ISO format by inserting the missing delimiters:

```js
var dateToParse = "20191116T202021.000Z";

var test = Date.parse(dateToParse.replace(/(....)(..)(..T..)(..)/, "$1-$2-$3:$4:")); 
console.log(test); // output as milliseconds
console.log(new Date(test).toJSON()); // output also in JSON format
```

As noted below, the above regular expression already does the work of parsing the string into its date parts, so you might as well pass those parts to `Date.UTC` without building another string that needs parsing again. It just needs a little adjustment for the month number:

```js
var dateToParse = "20191116T202021.000Z";

var parts = dateToParse.match(/(....)(..)(..)T(..)(..)(..)\.(...)Z/);
var test = Date.UTC(parts[1], parts[2]-1, parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]); 
console.log(test); // output as milliseconds
console.log(new Date(test).toJSON()); // output also in JSON format
```

For more efficiency you would just slice the string into its fixed size pieces without the fancy regular expression:

```js
var dateToParse = "20191116T202021.000Z";

var test = Date.UTC(dateToParse.slice(0,4), 
                    dateToParse.slice(4,6)-1,
                    dateToParse.slice(6,8),
                    dateToParse.slice(9,11), 
                    dateToParse.slice(11,13),
                    dateToParse.slice(13,15),
                    dateToParse.slice(16,19));

console.log(test); // output as milliseconds
console.log(new Date(test).toJSON()); // output also in JSON format
```

Comment: Great trick with this parsing. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, @RobG. Passing the parts directly to `Date.UTC` is more efficient. Not forgetting of course that the month number needs adjusting in that process. Added it to the answer.